# How to do sum with querying data on firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to do sum with querying data.
I am using ionic and firebase.
My data is simple like:

```
vitaly:{count:2,group:1}
kristina:{count:1,group:2}
yuri:{count:1,group:1}
dana:{count:1,group:3}
mark:{count:4,group:1}
```

is possible to get sum of count by group like: 
group:1 count:7
.....

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do the summation client side but to select your groups you can (depending on you're framework)

```
 .orderByChild('group').equalTo(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
newsRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
   var sum = 0;
   snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
   sum += (childSnapshot.val().sth);
});
console.log('NUM '+sum);
```